# Can I hide only public/global chats in Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I know that I can disable all chat messages in Minecraft, but is there a way I can hide just the public/global chatter, but still see and send direct chat messages?

Comment: I don't think you can. But there might be a client-side mod that does it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on the server. Your client "flattens" all chat, so there's only one on/off switch in the Minecraft settings. Sometimes, depending on plugins, you can turn off server broadcasts, but most want you to hear about their limited-time deals.